# Summarise columns by different functions with data.table

Tags: r, data.table

Suppose `df` is a datatable with many columns. I want to group by `variable1` and summarise the datatable with function `f` for all the variables in `variables_f` and summarise with `g` for all the variables in `variables_g`

Comment: Fyi, it's usually best to provide a concrete example, like akrun did in his "data" section below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that 'variables_f' and 'variables_g' are `vector` of `character` strings representing the column names, we group by 'variable1', get the values of these `vector`s in a `list` with `mget`, loop through `lapply`, apply the functions `f` and `g` and then concatenate (`c`) together

```
df[,  c(lapply(mget(variables_f), f), 
         lapply(mget(variables_g), g)), by = variable1]
```

#### data

```
set.seed(24)
df <- data.frame(variable1 = rep(LETTERS[1:5], each = 2), 
           matrix(sample(1:9, 10*20, replace=TRUE), ncol=20,
          dimnames = list(NULL,  
 c(paste0('var_f', 1:10), paste0('var_g', 1:10)))))
setDT(df)
variables_f <- paste0("var_f", 1:10)
variables_g <- paste0("var_g", 1:10)

f <- function(x) mean(x)
g <- function(x) max(x)
```